# aggregating data frames by sum

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have two data frames as follows.

```
d1 = data.frame(table(c(1,2,2,2,4,5)))
d2 = data.frame(table(c(2,2,2,6)))
```

Combing the frames with `rbind` gives the following:

```
> rbind(d1, d2)
  Var1 Freq
1    1    1
2    2    3
3    4    1
4    5    1
5    2    3
6    5    1
```

But what I would like is to calculate the sum of the `Freq` values with the same `Var1`, i.e. get

```
  Var1 Freq
1    1    1
2    2    6
3    4    1
4    5    1
5    6    1
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: +1 for a reproducible question. But this is a pretty common one. You should search `aggregate` tag. `aggregate(data=rbind(d1,d2), Freq ~ Var1, sum)`

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure what to search for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to `aggregate`, there is also `xtabs` which is designed specifically for summing up tables.

```
xtabs(Freq ~ Var1, data=rbind(d1, d2))
```

Comment: This doesn't return a data frame though. Easily fixed by wrapping in `data.frame()`.